# How do I download a JPG file from Amazon S3 into memory using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm struggling to download a JPG file from Amazon S3 using Python, I want to load this code onto Heroku so I need to the image to be loaded into memory rather than onto disk.

The code I'm using is:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id = access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key = access_secret
    )

s3.upload_fileobj(image_conv, bucket, Key = "image_3.jpg")

new_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="image_3.jpg")

image_dl = new_obj['Body'].read()

Image.open(image_dl)
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
File ..... line 2968, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Calling image_dl returns a massive long list of what I assume are bytes, one small section looks like the following:

```
f\xbc\xdc\x8f\xfe\xb5q\xda}\xed\xcb\xdcD\xab\xe6o\x1c;\xb7\xa0\xf5\xf5\xae\xa6)\xbe\xee\xe6\xc3vn\xdfLVW:\x96\xa8\xa3}\xa4\xd8\xea\x8f*\x89\xd7\xcc\xe8\xf0\xca\xb9\x0b\xf4\x1f\xe7\x15\x93\x0f\x83ty$h\xa6\x83\xc8\x99z<K\xc3c\xd4w\xae\xa4\xc2\xfb\xcb\xee\xe0
```

The image before I uploaded to S3 returned the below and that's the format that I'm trying to return the image into. Is anyone able to help me on where I'm going wrong?

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1440x1440 at 0x7F2BB4005EB0>
```

Comment: Would also be interesting to see how you get the image data (new_obj)

Comment: Apologies that's been updated now to show how I pulled new_obj

Comment: updated my answer: use StringIO and download_fileobj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pillow's Image class needs either a filename to open, or a file-like object that it can call `read` on.  Since you don't have a filename, you'll need to provide a stream.  It's easiest to use `BytesIO` to turn the byte array into a strem:

```python
import boto3
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

bucket = "--example-bucket--"

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_conv:
    s3.upload_fileobj(image_conv, bucket, Key="image_3.jpg")
new_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="image_3.jpg")
image_dl = new_obj['Body'].read()
image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_dl))

print(image.width, image.height)
```

Comment: Hero! Thank you so much, worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try first to load raw data into a BytesIO container:

```
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image

file_stream = StringIO()
s3.download_fileobj(bucket, "image_3.jpg", file_stream)
img = Image.open(file_stream)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this then gives the error: ```File .... in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f2bd1d03db0>```

Comment: This gives the error ```TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'``` when I try to run the ```s3.download_filobj(...)``` line. I tried to re-upload the file in a StringIO container rather than a BytesIO but that was giving an error as well.